# What actually high and low means in a ranges table

Tags: range, abap

The range table contains the high and a low value. What it actually does and used for?

Comment: Have you even tried to research this? This is an extremely basic question.

Answer (score 3):

the range table can be used in `open sql` queries (using the `IN` clause) as a restriction. You can define several ranges to include or exclude in your query result. For instance:

```
report ZZTEST.

types: 
  lt_kunrng type range of kunnr_d.

data:
  it_rnrng type standard table of lt_kunrng,
  wa_rnrng type lt_kunrng,
  it_kna1 type standard table of kna1.

START-OF-SELECTION.

move:
  'I' to  wa_rnrng-sign,
  'EQ' to wa_rnrng-option,
  '0001000000' to wa_rnrng-low,
  '0002999999' to wa_rnrng-high.
append wa_rnrng to it_rnrng.

move:
  'I' to  wa_rnrng-sign,
  'EQ' to wa_rnrng-option,
  '0003500000' to wa_rnrng-low,
append wa_rnrng to it_rnrng.

select * from kna1 into corresponding fields of table it_kna1
    where kna1~kunnr in it_rnrng.
```

this example defines a `RANGE` table manually, adds two rows to it and then queries transparent table `KNA1` with this range table. The internal table `it_kna1` should then contain all `KNA1` records with `KUNNR` between 1000000 and 2999999 and the record with `KUNNR` 35000000. So you can combine several ranges in a single range table.

The field `SIGN` contains either 'I' for Include or 'E' for Exclude (meaning that this row should include or exclude records matching the defined range), the field `OPTION` defines the comparer ('EQ' for equal, 'GT' for greater than, 'GE' for greater or equal and so forth). Fields `HIGH` and `LOW` contain the actual ranges. If you only want to query a single value you don't have to supply both `LOW` and `HIGH`, you only need to supply field `LOW` (and of course `SIGN` and `OPTION`).

`RANGE` table are also created when you define a `SELECT-OPTION` in a report. Users can then use the selection screen to define the ranges they want to use in the report.

```
REPORT ZZTEST.

TABLES: kna1.

DATA: it_kna1 type standard table of kna1.

SELECT-OPTION:
  so_kndrng for kna1-kunnr.

START-OF-SELECTION.

select * from kna1 into corresponding fields of it_kna1
  where kna1~kunnr in so_kndrng.
```

For further information regarding range tables you can also refer to the official documentation [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/dba71f35c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm)

Comment: Usage of range tables isn't restricted to open SQL. It can also be used in if statements, etc.