# Range table and IN not behaving properly

Tags: select, parameters, abap, opensql

The program just selects everything if the carrid is ok even if it is not ok with the lt_spfli. And there aren't any entries with that carrid it gets runtime error. If I try with for all entries he just selects absolutely the entire SFLIGHT.

```
PARAMETERS: pa_airp TYPE S_FROMAIRP,
            pa_carid TYPE S_CARR_ID.
DATA: lt_spfli TYPE RANGE OF SPFLI,
      lt_sflight TYPE TABLE OF SFLIGHT.

SELECT CONNID FROM SPFLI
INTO TABLE lt_spfli
WHERE AIRPFROM = pa_airp.

SELECT * FROM SFLIGHT
INTO TABLE lt_sflight
WHERE CARRID = pa_carid AND CONNID in lt_spfli.
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are actually trying to achieve and what the perceived problem might be. Very likely you have not read the keyword documentation and ran into one of the misunderstandings that have already been explained a thousand times, but I honestly can't tell.

Comment: What do you actually want?

Comment: Why don't you `JOIN`?

Comment: And if the `SELECT` results in the whole table when using `FOR ALL ENTRIES` - your `lt_spfli` in 99% of the cases, is just empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just suppose, that you want every flight connection from a given airport...

Notice, that a `RANGE` structure has two more fields in front of the actual "compare value". So selecting directly into it will result in a very gibberish table.

### **Possible Solutions:**

*Selecting with `RANGE`*

If you really want to use this temporary table, you can have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227917/abap-hard-code-value-into-select-and-field-into-another-field/39229260#39229260) where I describe the way to fill `RANGE`s without any overhead. After this step, your current snippet will work the way to wanted it too. Just make sure, that it really has been filled or everything will be selected.

---

*Selecting with `FOR ALL ENTRIES`*

Before you use this variant you should make absolutely sure, that your specified data object is filled. Otherwise it will result in the same mess as the first solution. To do that, you could write:

```
* select connid
IF lt_spfli[] IS NOT INITIAL.
*    select on SFLIGHT
ELSE.
*    no result
ENDIF.
```

---

*Selecting with `JOIN`*

The "correct" approach in this case would be a `JOIN` like:

```
SELECT t~* 
  FROM spfli AS i
  JOIN sflight AS t
    ON t~carrid = @pa_carid
   AND t~connid = i~connid
  INTO TABLE @DATA(li_conns)
  WHERE i~airpfrom = @pa_airp.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FOR ALL ENTRIES` instead of `CONNID in lt_SPFLI`.

As so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sflight 
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_spfli 
  WHERE carrid = pa_carid 
    AND connid = lt_spfli-connid
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what a "Ranges Table" is. You fill it incorrectly.

This part of your code demonstrates the misunderstanding (with a little debug, you would see the erroneous contents immediately):

```
DATA: lt_spfli TYPE RANGE OF SPFLI.

SELECT CONNID FROM SPFLI INTO TABLE lt_spfli ...
```

A "Ranges Table" is an internal table with 4 components (SIGN, OPTION, LOW, HIGH), used in Open SQL to do complex selections on one database column (NB: it can also be used in several ABAP statements to test the value of an ABAP variable).

So, with your SQL statement, you only initialize the first component of the Ranges table, while you should transfer `CONNID` into the third component.

In "modern" Open SQL, you'd better do:

```
SELECT 'I' as SIGN, 'EQ' as OPTION, CONNID as LOW FROM SPFLI INTO TABLE @lt_spfli ...
```

For more information about Ranges Tables, you may refer to the answer here: [What actually high and low means in a ranges table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891895/what-actually-high-and-low-means-in-a-ranges-table)